# Search for a node or nodes in non binary tree and get results from root to the searched nodes

Tags: java, search

Trying to search for  node/nodes in a tree and get its descendants.

My class

```
public class TreeNodeDTO {

/** The id. */
private String id;

/** The title. */
private String title;

/** The children. */
private List<TreeNodeDTO> children;

//setters and getters
}
```

I am able to find descendants by following algorithm

```
  public ArrayList< TreeNodeDTO > search( String search ) {
    ArrayList< TreeNodeDTO > list = new ArrayList< TreeNodeDTO >(), temp;
    if ( !this.title.equals( "Root" ) ) {
        list.add( this );
    }
    if ( getTitle().equals( search ) ) {
        return list;
    }
    if ( children != null )
        for ( TreeNodeDTO n : children ) {
            temp = n.search( search );
            if ( temp != null ) {
                list.addAll( temp );
                return list;
            }
        }
    return new ArrayList<>();
  }
```

But its returning all the paths from parent to child like for example if this class is populated with the following tree structure:

```
Data
  |
  Workflows
   |
   Elements
    |
    Export
```

When i search **"Export"**

it returns

```
Data
  |
  Workflows
   |
   Elements
    |
    Export
```

and

```
Workflows
   |
   Elements
    |
    Export
```

and

```
Elements
 |
 Export
```

While i only need the following result

```
Data
  |
  Workflows
   |
   Elements
    |
    Export
```

Comment: You are revisiting the path that is already visited, i.e instead of creating a new Array list at every instance, you need to pass the arrayList created previously and add to it.

Comment: First few questions.
- In the search implementation do you have only 1 path to any given word or multiple path? 
- Secondly, this appears to be a Trie search implementation that you are trying to replicate. However, instead of returning near match or fuzzy match term, you are trying to fetch the path from root to term node. In that case, take a look at this solution, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/105136/path-sum-in-binary-tree,you just need to store the path, instead of adding the sum.

Comment: There may be multiple paths as one node with the same title can exist or can be a child of some other node. So a single search may return multiple paths from parent to its child. i, e Data node may have a child with the name testProject and another child of data node may have its own child with the name testProject! So searching testProject should return both  paths.